# Prototype Selectors like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, css-selectors

Just trying to establish whether prototype can do something like

```
$$('#ID a:last').css('color','#111');
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
$$('#ID a:last')[0].setStyle('color','#111');
```

In Prototype, `$$` returns an array - so if you know there is just one, take the first.

Comment: hey thanks - yeah i had to set it to

$$('#ID a:last')[1].setStyle('color','#111');

this worked